# Context vector with norm 1

Tags: multiarmed-bandit, contextual-bandit

Very often in the literature authors state something like: "*We consider a contextual linear bandit problem where at each round t, the learner receives a context vector $x_t \in R^d$ with norm 1*".

**Questions:** Is the norm 1 assumption useful only for proving regret bounds, or are there other reasons for it? What happens if this assumption does not hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**: $\|x\|\le L$ is often assumed because it simplifies the analysis on regret bounds but is absolutely without loss of generality. Indeed, many other papers use the assumption that $\|x\|\le L$ for some $L>0$ (see e.g. Sec. 2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.6110).

Assuming $L = 1$ as in the paper mentioned in your question allows avoiding mentioning the dependence on $L$ in the regret guarantees and improves clarity in the expressions.